# The "metadata.json" file for the box 'laravel/homestead' was not found

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

OC: Windows 10.
Vagrant: 2.2.1.

I run:

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead --provider virtualbox`

and got an error:

```
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v6.4.0) for provider: virtualbox
The "metadata.json" file for the box 'laravel/homestead' was not found.
Boxes require this file in order for Vagrant to determine the
provider it was made for. If you made the box, please add a
"metadata.json" file to it. If someone else made the box, please
notify the box creator that the box is corrupt. Documentation for
box file format can be found at the URL below:

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/format.html
```

[image]

Before that, I had already executed this command, I added the box and everything worked for me, but then I decided to remove the box through `vagrant box remove laravel/homestead` and add it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by deleting the `laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead` folder inside the `~\.vagrant.d\boxes` directory (`C:\Users\User\.vagrant.d\boxes` im my case).

After this i successfully run:

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead --provider virtualbox
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v6.4.0) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.4.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    box: Download redirected to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com
    box:
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v6.4.0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: After doing this, I received the error, `Failed to Power on with Error 'The chain of virtual hard disks is broken. The system cannot locate the parent virtual hard disk for the differencing disk.` I resolved this by deleting the `.vagrant` directory inside the cloned Homestead repository and then ran `vagrant up` -- problem solved!